# jQuery mobile adds a space after list-entries

Tags: php, jquery, json, listview, jquery-mobile

I retrieve data from php and add them to a listview dynamically. If I add just static data "on the fly" everything seems perfect, but when the data is retrieved from a php file jQuery Mobile adds a space after my list-entries. Is there a known problem?!

My js-file looks like:

```
        userda = '';
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "userdata.php",
           data: {"iduser": iduser},
           dataType: 'json',
           cache: false,
           success: function(data1){
           userda += '<li data-role="list-divider">Name</li>';
           userda += '<li>'+data1.data.fname+' '+data1.data.lname+'</li>';
           userda += '<li data-role="list-divider">Money</li>';
           userda += '<li>'+data1.data.money+'</li>';
           userda += '<li data-role="list-divider">Headlines</li>';
           $.each(data1.headlines, function(i, currentObj) {
                  userda += '<li>' + currentObj + '</li>​';
                  });
           $('ul#userdatalist').html(userda).listview('refresh');
           }
           });
```

My HTML file looks like

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-divider-theme="a" id="userdatalist">
                    </ul>
```

And the (json) data looks like:

```
{"data":{"fname":"test","lname":"test","money":"47"},"headlines":["Promis","Unterhaltung","Unterwaesche"]}
```

And the result looks like: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/705/bildschirmfoto20120619uj.png/

I can't see any problems, but I my second listview I have the same problem.

Comment: What does your CSS look like?

Comment: thats a good point. i have several css files, i will look at them! but another question: is the jquery.js and jquery-mobile.js needed for working with jquery-mobile? because when i delete one of them i loose all the theming in my app. because i wanted to use zepto.js for loading purpose...

Comment: Yes they are both needed for jQM to work. You can't just swap zepto for jquery and expect it to work, but you *can* mimic the DOM and use their css files ;)

Comment: thanks. so now i've deleted all my .css files, and just included the jquery-mobile.css and jquery-mobile.js and jquery.js, but the problem is not solved... same picture as always...

Comment: if you deleted the css files then it defos shouldn't still look like that. can you try clearing your browser cache, or disabling browser caching in the gear on chromes developer console?

Comment: Hm.. I'm not testing that in my browser, i'm testing it on the iphone simulator through xcode...

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas:

1. do you by chance have any .live() or .delegate() functions that might mess up your list?
2. you could try to use standard for-loop and combine with jquery (since you are using standard js and not jquery in 'success') or use jquery consequently in your .each()-loop:

   ```
   var $ul = $('ul#userdatalist'); // selector to the ul being filled 
                                   // (btw: since an id has to be unique, 
                                   // it is useless to prepend the tagType

   $ul.append(userda); // this is the jquery way -
                       // more or less ;)

   for (var i = 0;i < data1.headlines.length; i++) {
       $e = $("<li/>").text(data1.headlines[i]); // you could do this in your 
                                                 //.each()-loop as well, thus 
       $u.append($e);                            // sticking to jquery            
   }
   ```